# source address in TCP connection

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp

I have a system with 6 interfaces (and 6 IP addresses). I want to set up a TCP client connection (C++) to a server. Is there a way to use a certain interface as a source address (without using RAW sockets)?

Comment: You can `bind` a socket to a specific interface. Use port `0` to get a random port (see e.g. [this old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1077305/440558)).

Comment: I thought bind was only used when setting up a server connection?

Comment: Indeed, bind does it. A code snippet:
Socket s = new Socket;
s.bind (new (InetSocketAddress (localAddress,localPort));
s.connect (new (InetSocketAddress (localAddress,localPort));