# How to check if a network port is open?

Tags: python, port, netstat

How can I know if a certain port is open/closed on linux ubuntu, not a remote system, using python? 
How can I list these open ports in python?

- Netstat: 
  Is there a way to integrate netstat output with python?

Answer (score 186):

You can using the [socket module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html) to simply check if a port is open or not.

It would look something like this.

```
import socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
result = sock.connect_ex(('127.0.0.1',80))
if result == 0:
   print "Port is open"
else:
   print "Port is not open"
sock.close()
```

Comment: This has obvious drawbacks that shall be noted: simply attempt to check connection could 1) fail due to firewall or temporary overflow, 2) trigger an unwanted reaction to connect attempt in case of any active protection, 3) simply spoil logs and statistics... Checking using specially dedicated tools as netstat is commonly preferred.

Comment: @Netch -- this is really handy when you are on a box you don't want to install extra tools on and need to check if a remote port is open . . .

Comment: @WyattBarnett netstat is not an extra tool (at least on *nix) :)

Comment: I published another answer with a quick jot of how I'd handle the temporary overflow issue, @Netch :)

Comment: Works on Windows, too.

Comment: Some organization requires elevated privilges to install additional tools. With this it become really really handy.

Comment: This caused warning when run in a unit test: `ResourceWarning: unclosed <socket.socket fd=3, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('0.0.0.0', 59726)>`.  Those warnings were mitigated by adding `sock.close()` after the line where `result` is set.

Comment: This seems to be slow on Windows 10 (one port per second).  It's a problem if you want to test a lot of ports.  It's fine on Linux.

Comment: @Netch how does netstat bypass logging and statistics? That sounds like a gigantic hole if netstat connection-attempts aren't recorded.

Comment: @NickT netstat doesn't make any connections, it analyzes socket list exported by regular kernel interface. Of course, this works only for localhost, but that is how the original question is restricted. Additionally, netstat not from root is usually unable to show foreign process that owns a port, but just the fact port is owned by some process.

Comment: UDP scan isn't working for me with py3.6 on windows, I get all ports open no matter what their state is.

Comment: @WyattBarnett in many environments production servers will have all extraneous tools removed. This often means no netstat, no telnet. Python however is often there as it is used by many other tools, e.g. Ansible. So a few lines of code like this to test a port is great to have in ones toolkit.

Comment: @TheDude Hello, regarding your edit suggestion, if you believe there's an issue/oversight with the answer, please write it as a comment and the OP will update the answer if they see fit. Editing is not for adding extra ideas into the answer. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/30155102).

Comment: You should use a timeout on the socket `socket.settimeout(1)`

Comment: This method doesn't consider ports with established connection as open.

Comment: If you use this approach to check a port with established connection, the connection will be reset/lost as I tried with Python asyncio.

Comment: Looks like `connect_ex(ip_addr, port)` returns `0` even when the port/protocol is not in the firewall whitelist on the destination machine. Any solution to this scenario?

Answer (score 150):

If you want to use this in a more general context, you should make sure, that the socket that you open also gets closed. So the check should be more like this:

```
import socket
from contextlib import closing
   
def check_socket(host, port):
    with closing(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)) as sock:
        if sock.connect_ex((host, port)) == 0:
            print("Port is open")
        else:
            print("Port is not open")
```

Comment: Upvoted for mentioning [Automatic Resource Management](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/). More people need to see this!

Comment: Hey Michael, thanks for the reply; a question, why would you use `connect_ex` instead of `bind`. Every attempt of mine to use connect or connect_ex on py3 and mac is failing with error 61 and then auto assigns a port to my socket followed by err 22. On the contrary, `bind`, does what I expect it to do, return if the port is open, throw if it is in use. Am I missing something?

Comment: @plumSemPy My answer was written for python2. In python3 socket already works as a context manager. So if bind works for you, perfect.

Comment: @Michael I know this is much later than original post, but I have a problem perhaps you could provide context to.. I tried your solution using `(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080)` but it always says the port is not open. The thing is though, it most certainly is open because I can initiate my port-forward command on the same host and port immediately after doing the check. I'm even checking in terminal to see the ports using this command `sudo lsof -iTCP -sTCP:LISTEN -n -P | grep -i --color 8080` and it confirms the port is open.

Answer (score 53):

For me the examples above would hang if the port wasn't open.  Line 4 shows use of **settimeout** to prevent hanging

```
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.settimeout(2)                                      #2 Second Timeout
result = sock.connect_ex(('127.0.0.1',80))
if result == 0:
  print 'port OPEN'
else:
  print 'port CLOSED, connect_ex returned: '+str(result)
```

Answer (score 26):

If you only care about the local machine, you can rely on the psutil package. You can either:

1. Check all ports used by a specific pid:

   ```
   proc = psutil.Process(pid)
   print proc.connections()
   ```
2. Check all ports used on the local machine:

   ```
   print psutil.net_connections()
   ```

It works on Windows too.

https://github.com/giampaolo/psutil

Comment: I usually avoid non-stdlib solutions, but gdi, psutil should just be in the stdlib, its too dang essential.

Comment: Part 2 is exactly what I was looking for, but psutil doesn't have a net_connections() function.  Is this not available in Python 2?  I'm in ubuntu.

Comment: @qwerty9967 no idea, I guess you should check if you can upgrade (both python if you have a pre-2.7 or the psutil package itself, preferably using `pip` and not apt-get/yum)

Answer (score 9):

I found multiple solutions in this post. But some solutions have a hanging issue or takeing too much time in case of the port is not opened.Try below solution :

```
import socket 

def port_check(HOST):
   s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   s.settimeout(2) #Timeout in case of port not open
   try:
      s.connect((HOST, 22)) #Port ,Here 22 is port 
      return True
   except:
      return False

port_check("127.0.1.1")
```

Answer (score 8):

Here's a fast multi-threaded port scanner:

```
from time import sleep
import socket, ipaddress, threading

max_threads = 50
final = {}
def check_port(ip, port):
    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) # TCP
        #sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM) # UDP
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(2.0) # seconds (float)
        result = sock.connect_ex((ip,port))
        if result == 0:
            # print ("Port is open")
            final[ip] = "OPEN"
        else:
            # print ("Port is closed/filtered")
            final[ip] = "CLOSED"
        sock.close()
    except:
        final[ip] = "EXCEPTION"
        
port = 22
for ip in ipaddress.IPv4Network('95.217.210.0/24'): 
    threading.Thread(target=check_port, args=[str(ip), port]).start()
    #sleep(0.1)

    # limit the number of threads.
    while threading.active_count() > max_threads :
        sleep(1)


sorted_ips = dict(sorted(final.items(), key=lambda item: tuple(map(int, item[0].split('.')))))

for ip, state in sorted_ips.items():
    print(ip, state)
```

---

[Live Demo](http://tpcg.io/_01GXLE)

Answer (score 6):

Just added to mrjandro's solution some improvements like automatic resource management (making sure that the opened socket also gets closed), handling timeouts, getting rid of simple connection errors / timeouts and printing out results:

```
import socket
from contextlib import closing

hosts = ["host1", "host2", "host3"]
port = 22
timeout_in_seconds = 2

hosts_with_opened_port = []
hosts_with_closed_port = []
hosts_with_errors = []


def check_port(host, port, timeout_in_seconds):
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    sock.settimeout(timeout_in_seconds)
    with closing(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)) as sock:
        try:
            result = sock.connect_ex((host, port))
            if result == 0:
                print("Port {} is *** OPEN *** on host: {}".format(port, host))
                hosts_with_opened_port.append(host)
            else:
                print("Port {} is not open on host: {}".format(port, host))
                hosts_with_closed_port.append(host)
        except socket.gaierror:
            print("Port {} check returns a network *** ERROR *** on host: {}".format(port, host))
            hosts_with_errors.append(host)


for host in hosts:
    check_port(host, port, timeout_in_seconds)

print("\nHosts with opened port:")
print(hosts_with_opened_port)
print("\nHosts with closed port:")
print(hosts_with_closed_port)
print("\nHosts with errors:")
print(hosts_with_errors)
```

Comment: Hi there!
You just need some minor changes to the print functions in there...
Check the new version I pasted :)

You can easily change it to not save data to a log file, for example.

Answer (score 5):

In case when you probing TCP ports with intention to listen on it, it’s better to actually call listen. The approach with tring to connect don’t 'see' client ports of established connections, because nobody listen on its. But these ports cannot be used to listen on its.

```
import socket


def check_port(port, rais=True):
    """ True -- it's possible to listen on this port for TCP/IPv4 or TCP/IPv6
    connections. False -- otherwise.
    """
    try:
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.bind(('127.0.0.1', port))
        sock.listen(5)
        sock.close()
        sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        sock.bind(('::1', port))
        sock.listen(5)
        sock.close()
    except socket.error as e:
        return False
        if rais:
            raise RuntimeError(
                "The server is already running on port {0}".format(port))
    return True
```

Comment: Using "magic numbers" like 5 without comment is bad practice.  According to docs, this argument socket.socket.listen(backlog) is the "number of unaccepted connections the system will allow".  It is unclear why your solution would not work with a backlog of '0', simply to test if a socket can be used for a listen endpoint.  (P.S. I like your solution better than the one that actually tries a connection)

Comment: This was what I was looking for. But if someone is just looking for any open port, perhaps binding to port 0 as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45690594/101923 is more appropriate.

Answer (score 5):

Building upon the `psutil` solution mentioned by Joe (only works for checking local ports):

```
import psutil
1111 in [i.laddr.port for i in psutil.net_connections()]
```

returns `True` if port 1111 currently used.

`psutil` is not part of python stdlib, so you'd need to `pip install psutil` first. It also needs python headers to be available, so you need something like `python-devel`

Comment: Does not seem to be working in MacOS with Operation not permitted error. Strange as other psutil functions are working just fine

Answer (score 4):

Agree with Sachin. Just one improvement, use connect_ex instead of connect, which can avoid try except

```
>>> def port_check(ip_port):
...     s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
...     s.settimeout(1)
...     return s.connect_ex(ip_port) == 0
... 
>>> port_check(loc)
True
>>> port_check(loc_x)
False
>>> loc
('10.3.157.24', 6443)
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

Netstat tool simply parses some /proc files like /proc/net/tcp and combines it with other files contents. Yep, it's highly platform specific, but for Linux-only solution you can stick with it. Linux kernel documentation describes these files in details so you can find there how to read them.

Please also notice your question is too ambiguous because "port" could also mean serial port (/dev/ttyS* and analogs), parallel port, etc.; I've reused understanding from another answer this is network port but I'd ask you to formulate your questions more accurately.

Answer (score 2):

Please check Michael answer and vote for it. It is the right way to check open ports. Netstat and other tools are not any use if you are developing services or daemons. For instance, I am crating modbus TCP server and client services for an industrial network. The services can listen to any port, but the question is whether that port is open? The program is going to be used in different places, and I cannot check them all manually, so this is what I did:

```
from contextlib import closing
import socket
class example:
    def __init__():

       self.machine_ip = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
       self.ready:bool = self.check_socket()

    def check_socket(self)->bool:
        result:bool = True
        with closing(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)) as sock:
        modbus_tcp_port:int = 502
        if not sock.connect_ex((self.machine_ip, modbus_tcp_port)) == 0:
            result = False
        return result
```

Answer (score 0):

This will find a random port in the given range:

```
import socket
import random 
from typing import Tuple

def find_listening_port(
    port_range:Tuple[int,int]=None, 
    host='', 
    socket_type='tcp', 
    default:int=None
) -> int:
    """Find an available listening port
    
    Arguments:
        port_range: Optional tuple of ports to randomly search, ``[min_port, max_port]``
            If omitted, then randomly search between ``[6000, 65534]``
        host: Host interface to search, if omitted then bind to all interfaces
        socket_type: The socket type, this should be ``tcp`` or ``udp``
        default: The port to try first before randomly searching the port range

    Returns:
        Available port for listening
    """
    def _test_port(host, port, socket_protocol):
        with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket_protocol) as sock:
            try:
                sock.bind((host, port))
                if socket_type == 'tcp':
                    sock.listen(1)
                return port
            except:
                pass 

        return -1

    if port_range is None:
        port_range = (6000,65534)

    if socket_type == 'tcp':
        socket_protocol = socket.SOCK_STREAM
    elif socket_type == 'udp':
        socket_protocol = socket.SOCK_DGRAM
    else:
        raise Exception('Invalid socket_type argument, must be: tcp or udp')

    searched_ports = []
    if default is not None:
        port = _test_port(host, default, socket_protocol)
        if port != -1:
            return port
        searched_ports.append(default)

    for _ in range(100):
        port = random.randint(port_range[0], port_range[1])
        if port in searched_ports:
            continue 

        port = _test_port(host, port, socket_protocol)
        if port != -1:
            return port

        searched_ports.append(port)

    raise Exception(f'Failed to find {socket_type} listening port for host={host}')
```

Example usage:

```
# Find a TCP port,
# first check if port 80 is availble
port = find_listening_port(
    port_range=(4000, 60000),
    host='',
    socket_type='tcp',
    default=80
)
print(f'Available TCP port: {port}')
```