# How Can I Run a Streamlit App from within a Python Script?

Tags: python, streamlit

Is there a way to run the command `streamlit run APP_NAME.py` from within a python script, that might look something like:

```
import streamlit
streamlit.run("APP_NAME.py")
```

As the project I'm working on needs to be cross-platform (and packaged), I can't safely rely on a call to `os.system(...)` or `subprocess`.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hopefully this works for others:
I looked into the actual streamlit file in my python/conda bin, and it had these lines:

```
import re
import sys
from streamlit.cli import main

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv[0] = re.sub(r'(-script\.pyw|\.exe)?$', '', sys.argv[0])
    sys.exit(main())
```

From here, you can see that running `streamlit run APP_NAME.py` on the command line is the same (in python) as:

```
import sys
from streamlit import cli as stcli

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv = ["streamlit", "run", "APP_NAME.py"]
    sys.exit(stcli.main())
```

So I put that in another script, and then run that script to run the original app from python, and it seemed to work. I'm not sure how cross-platform this answer is though, as it still relies somewhat on command line args.

Comment: **Broken.** The `streamlit.cli` submodule no longer exists as of Streamlit 0.12.0: `ImportError: cannot import name 'cli' from 'streamlit' (/usr/lib/python3.10/site-packages/streamlit/__init__.py)`. Unstable upstream APIs is why we can't have stable StackOverflow answers. `</sigh>`

Comment: **Update:** [the `streamlit.cli` submodule has been moved to `streamlit.web.cli`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73523578/2809027). I can personally verify that the API otherwise appears to be identical. Gah! Why wouldn't Streamlit just add a simple alias from the latter to the former to preserve backward compatibility? That's *not* a good look in 2022, Streamlit – seriously. *Not cool.*

Comment: Bear in mind it may break again. The streamlit developers consider it internal. See here: https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/run-streamlit-from-pycharm/21624/3

Comment: Update: from streamlit.web import cli as stcli

Answer (score 8):

You can run your script from python as `python my_script.py`:

```
import sys
from streamlit import cli as stcli
import streamlit
    
def main():
# Your streamlit code

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if streamlit._is_running_with_streamlit:
        main()
    else:
        sys.argv = ["streamlit", "run", sys.argv[0]]
        sys.exit(stcli.main())
```

Comment: While clever, violating privacy encapsulation by directly testing `streamlit._is_running_with_streamlit` is *not* a production-hardened solution. The Streamlit API moves rapidly. If this hasn't already broke, it probably will shortly.

Comment: @CecilCurry `streamlit._is_running_with_streamlit` doesn't work anymore now. Do you know the latest update for this?

Comment: You can query the port streamlit runs on and verify that the process matches streamlit: [How to check if a network port is open?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196105/how-to-check-if-a-network-port-is-open)

Comment: Now there is a better solution: `from streamlit import runtime` and `runtime.exists()` instead of `streamlit._is_running_with_streamlit`

Answer (score 6):

I prefer working with subprocess and it makes executing many scripts via another python script very easy.

`The subprocess module allows you to spawn new processes, connect to their input/output/error pipes, and obtain their return codes. This module intends to replace several older modules and functions:`

```py
import subprocess
import os

process = subprocess.Popen(["streamlit", "run", os.path.join(
            'application', 'main', 'services', 'streamlit_app.py')])
```

Comment: `subprocess.run("streamlit run app.py")` works too, which is now the preferred option, see https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run

Answer (score 4):

With the current streamlit version 1.21.0 the following works:

```
import streamlit.web.bootstrap
streamlit.web.bootstrap.run("APP_NAME.py", '', [], [])
```

Execute `?streamlit.web.bootstrap.run` do get more info on the different options for `streamlit.web.bootstrap.run`. For example, you can provide some args to the script.

Comment: This is not recommended by the developers as it uses an internal API (which already moved once). See here: https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/5471#issuecomment-1269076238

Answer (score 1):

```
import sys
from streamlit.web import cli as stcli

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.argv = ["streamlit", "run", "app.py"]
    sys.exit(stcli.main())
```

Comment: Hi, Harshit! This question already has a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I am using is the following:

1. Write the streamlit app to the temporary directory of the computer.
2. Extecute the streamlit app.
3. Remove the streamlit app again.

```py
import os
import subprocess
import tempfile

def run_streamlit_app(app):
    # create a temporary directory
    temp_dir = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
    temp_file_path = os.path.join(temp_dir.name, 'app.py')
    
    # write the streamlit app code to a Python script in the temporary directory
    with open(temp_file_path, 'w') as f:
        f.write(app)
    
    # execute the streamlit app
    try:
        # execute the streamlit app
        subprocess.run(
            ["/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/miniforge/base/envs/machinelearning/bin/streamlit", "run", temp_file_path],
            stderr=subprocess.DEVNULL
        )
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass
    
    # clean up the temporary directory when done
    temp_dir.cleanup()
```

where an example could look like the following:

```py
app = """
import streamlit as st
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.normal(1, 1, size=100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.hist(arr, bins=20)

st.pyplot(fig)
"""
run_streamlit_app(app)
```