# No module named 'streamlit.cli'

Tags: python, macos, visual-studio-code, anaconda, streamlit

I am using MAC and downloaded the streamlit package using conda-forge.
I am getting an error message as below.

> from streamlit.cli import main ModuleNotFoundError: No module named
> 'streamlit.cli'

I have checked a stackoverflow post with the same issue, and it recommends installing networkx to fix this issue, but no help in my case.

If you have any suggestions, please let me know.

---

Edit

I added some more information based on merv's suggestion.

**Q. commands used to install streamlit**

A. conda install -c conda-forge streamlit

**Q. how I activate the Conda environment**

A. conda create --name web-app python=3.9

conda activate web-app

**Q. how you start Python**

A. I used vs code and set the interpreter to the env that I created and also on the vscode terminal activated env that I created.
Then I typed "streamlit hello"m and I was getting the error.

**Q. conda list output**

A.

This file may be used to create an environment using:

$ conda create --name  --file

platform: osx-64

```
abseil-cpp=20211102.0=h96cf925_1
altair=4.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
appnope=0.1.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
arrow-cpp=8.0.0=py39had1886b_0
asttokens=2.0.8=pyhd8ed1ab_0
attrs=22.1.0=pyh71513ae_1
aws-c-common=0.4.57=hb1e8313_1
aws-c-event-stream=0.1.6=h23ab428_5
aws-checksums=0.1.9=hb1e8313_0
aws-sdk-cpp=1.8.185=he271ece_0
backcall=0.2.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
backports=1.0=py_2
backports.functools_lru_cache=1.6.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
blinker=1.4=py_1
boost-cpp=1.80.0=h97e07a4_0
brotli=1.0.9=h5eb16cf_7
brotli-bin=1.0.9=h5eb16cf_7
brotlipy=0.7.0=py39h63b48b0_1004
bzip2=1.0.8=h0d85af4_4
c-ares=1.18.1=h0d85af4_0
ca-certificates=2022.6.15=h033912b_0
cachetools=5.2.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
certifi=2022.6.15=pyhd8ed1ab_1
cffi=1.15.1=py39hae9ecf2_0
charset-normalizer=2.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
click=8.1.3=py39h6e9494a_0
commonmark=0.9.1=py_0
cryptography=37.0.4=py39h9c2a9ce_0
dataclasses=0.8=pyhc8e2a94_3
debugpy=1.6.3=py39hd91caee_0
decorator=5.1.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
entrypoints=0.4=pyhd8ed1ab_0
executing=0.10.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
freetype=2.12.1=h3f81eb7_0
future=0.18.2=py39h6e9494a_5
gflags=2.2.2=hb1e8313_1004
gitdb=4.0.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
gitpython=3.1.27=pyhd8ed1ab_0
glog=0.6.0=h8ac2a54_0
grpc-cpp=1.46.1=h067a048_0
icu=70.1=h96cf925_0
idna=3.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
importlib-metadata=4.11.4=py39h6e9494a_0
importlib_resources=5.9.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
ipykernel=6.15.1=pyh736e0ef_0
ipython=8.4.0=pyhd1c38e8_1
ipython_genutils=0.2.0=py_1
ipywidgets=8.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
jedi=0.18.1=pyhd8ed1ab_2
jinja2=3.1.2=pyhd8ed1ab_1
jpeg=9e=hac89ed1_2
jsonschema=4.14.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
jupyter_client=7.3.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
jupyter_core=4.11.1=py39h6e9494a_0
jupyterlab_widgets=3.0.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
krb5=1.19.3=hb49756b_0
lcms2=2.12=h577c468_0
lerc=4.0.0=hb486fe8_0
libblas=3.9.0=16_osx64_openblas
libbrotlicommon=1.0.9=h5eb16cf_7
libbrotlidec=1.0.9=h5eb16cf_7
libbrotlienc=1.0.9=h5eb16cf_7
libcblas=3.9.0=16_osx64_openblas
libcurl=7.83.1=h372c54d_0
libcxx=14.0.6=hce7ea42_0
libdeflate=1.13=h775f41a_0
libedit=3.1.20191231=h0678c8f_2
libev=4.33=haf1e3a3_1
libevent=2.1.10=h815e4d9_4
libffi=3.4.2=h0d85af4_5
libgfortran=5.0.0=10_4_0_h97931a8_25
libgfortran5=11.3.0=h082f757_25
liblapack=3.9.0=16_osx64_openblas
libnghttp2=1.47.0=h7cbc4dc_1
libopenblas=0.3.21=openmp_h947e540_2
libpng=1.6.37=h5481273_4
libprotobuf=3.20.1=hfa58983_1
libsodium=1.0.18=hbcb3906_1
libsqlite=3.39.2=h5a3d3bf_1
libssh2=1.10.0=h7535e13_3
libthrift=0.15.0=h054ceb0_0
libtiff=4.4.0=h5e0c7b4_3
libwebp-base=1.2.4=h775f41a_0
libxcb=1.13=h0d85af4_1004
libzlib=1.2.12=hfe4f2af_2
llvm-openmp=14.0.4=ha654fa7_0
lz4-c=1.9.3=he49afe7_1
markupsafe=2.1.1=py39h63b48b0_1
matplotlib-inline=0.1.6=pyhd8ed1ab_0
nbformat=5.4.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
ncurses=6.3=h96cf925_1
nest-asyncio=1.5.5=pyhd8ed1ab_0
numpy=1.23.2=py39h62c883e_0
openjpeg=2.5.0=h5d0d7b0_1
openssl=1.1.1q=hfe4f2af_0
orc=1.7.4=h9274d09_0
packaging=21.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
pandas=1.4.3=py39hf72b562_0
parso=0.8.3=pyhd8ed1ab_0
pexpect=4.8.0=pyh9f0ad1d_2
pickleshare=0.7.5=py_1003
pillow=9.2.0=py39h4d560c1_2
pip=22.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
pkgutil-resolve-name=1.3.10=pyhd8ed1ab_0
prompt-toolkit=3.0.30=pyha770c72_0
protobuf=3.20.1=py39hd408605_0
psutil=5.9.1=py39h701faf5_0
pthread-stubs=0.4=hc929b4f_1001
ptyprocess=0.7.0=pyhd3deb0d_0
pure_eval=0.2.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
pyarrow=8.0.0=py39h2202ef3_0
pycparser=2.21=pyhd8ed1ab_0
pydeck=0.7.1=pyh6c4a22f_0
pygments=2.13.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
pympler=1.0.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
pyopenssl=22.0.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
pyparsing=3.0.9=pyhd8ed1ab_0
pyrsistent=0.18.1=py39h63b48b0_1
pysocks=1.7.1=pyha2e5f31_6
python=3.9.13=h57e37ff_0_cpython
python-dateutil=2.8.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
python-fastjsonschema=2.16.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
python-tzdata=2022.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
python_abi=3.9=2_cp39
pytz=2022.2.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
pytz-deprecation-shim=0.1.0.post0=py39h6e9494a_2
pyyaml=6.0=py39h63b48b0_4
pyzmq=23.2.1=py39h74f9307_0
re2=2022.04.01=h96cf925_0
readline=8.1.2=h3899abd_0
requests=2.28.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
rich=12.5.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
semver=2.13.0=pyh9f0ad1d_0
setuptools=65.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_1
six=1.16.0=pyh6c4a22f_0
smmap=3.0.5=pyh44b312d_0
snappy=1.1.9=h6e38e02_1
sqlite=3.39.2=hd9f0692_1
stack_data=0.5.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
streamlit=1.12.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
tk=8.6.12=h5dbffcc_0
toml=0.10.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
toolz=0.12.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
tornado=6.2=py39h701faf5_0
traitlets=5.3.0=pyhd8ed1ab_0
typing_extensions=4.3.0=pyha770c72_0
tzdata=2022c=h191b570_0
tzlocal=4.2=py39h6e9494a_1
urllib3=1.26.11=pyhd8ed1ab_0
utf8proc=2.6.1=h9ed2024_0
validators=0.18.2=pyhd3deb0d_0
watchdog=2.1.9=py39h0056ad7_0
wcwidth=0.2.5=pyh9f0ad1d_2
wheel=0.37.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
widgetsnbextension=4.0.2=pyhd8ed1ab_0
xorg-libxau=1.0.9=h35c211d_0
xorg-libxdmcp=1.1.3=h35c211d_0
xz=5.2.6=h775f41a_0
yaml=0.2.5=h0d85af4_2
zeromq=4.3.4=he49afe7_1
zipp=3.8.1=pyhd8ed1ab_0
zlib=1.2.12=hfe4f2af_2
zstd=1.5.2=hfa58983_4
```

Comment: Merv, thank you for your suggestion, and I updated the post based on your suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the update! From what I recall from other posts, VSCode’s terminal doesn’t work out-of-of-the-box with Conda environment activation. Maybe search around for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the response in [github](https://github.com/streamlit/streamlit/issues/5146#issuecomment-1223306586).

Use `streamlit.web.cli` instead of `streamlit.cli`

Comment: How can I change from streamlit.cli to streamlit.web.cli? Do I need to go to source code and change it?

Comment: @user715519 This problem is also recently raised in GitHub. Perhaps waiting for the package update is the best way.

Comment: The Conda Forge recipe [has been patched](https://github.com/conda-forge/streamlit-feedstock/pull/60) and the updated build released. So `conda update streamlit`

Comment: Wonderful, It is working now! Thank you, MingJie and Merv, for helping me out. I know this is irrelevant to this post, but I want to know what would be the general step to follow when conda-forge does not work. 
1) Dig in and try to figure out what how to make conda-forge work, or is it okay to go ahead and pip install? 

2) What would be the issue with mixing pip and conda?

Answer (score 4):

I have had this same problem. I went on streamlit documentation. [Here](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/changelog). If you run this following command in terminal, the issue is solved.

```
pip install --upgrade streamlit
```

Answer (score 2):

Find your `streamlit-script.py` file. I use conda environments, so it is in
`anaconda3/envs/myenv/Scripts`. Open the file in a text editor and change

```
from streamlit.cli import main
```

to

```
from streamlit.web.cli import main
```