# use python's psutil to detect if port 80/443 are open

Tags: python, psutil

I want to use python's psutil locally to detect if port 80/443 are open. I'd be honest, I haven't really spent time learning python (I'm more of a PowerShell person).

Sorry for asking for the answer for my problem.

Comment: did you take a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19196105/how-to-check-if-a-network-port-is-open ? I think there should be some interesting answers for you

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far!