# Pick a free port number on localhost using Python, but avoid 1 specific port number

Tags: python, sockets, port

I am using this excellent answer to find a free port on python:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/1365284/1467402

I want this method to pick me any free port, except for a single number.
i.e, I want to get any free port except for 8000 since I am saving it for my application.

Is this possible using this method?

This is my code:

```
def get_free_port():
    import socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind(("",0))
    free_port = s.getsockname()[1]
    s.close
    return free_port
```

Thanks

Comment: A bit of a hack, but what about binding to 8000, finding a free port, then closing the 8000 connection?

Comment: Thanks, I guess it is the most simple solution :)

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a hack, but what about binding to 8000, finding a free port, then closing the 8000 connection? – David

Comment: Hi, I didn't chose this method since I didn't want to bind and un-bind port for my purpose. Eventually I just checked if the port bind is what I wanted to avoid, and if so I am trying again. Haven't found anything better...