# With Twisted python is there a mechanism to find a free port similar to socket.open?

Tags: python, twisted, message-queue

## Question

Similar to this question - [On localhost, how do I pick a free port number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1365265/on-localhost-how-do-i-pick-a-free-port-number)

Except Twisted abstracts away access to socket behind reactor methods like `listenTCP` or the `UDP` equivalent and I haven't found a mechanism where I can just tell the reactor to find a free socket and bind/listen to it.

Comment: Normally you do not want to use a random port for a server, otherwise how will you connect to it. if you really want a random port, then generate a random number, assign a socket to it, then test if it was successful.

Comment: @smac89 Originally it was related to 0MQ but I dropped that part of the question and have fixed most of the tags.

Comment: @ron I wrote a desktop process manager that spools up various twisted.web.Site applications on demand and they all emit to stderr a magic token that tells the manager which port the app is running on.    Similarly I am working on a project that uses multiple 0mq listening sockets to coordinate work between multiple processes and they all check into something like hadoop's zookeeper to report their address and port #'s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like so:

```
reactor.listenTCP(0, ...)
```

Comment: Thank you, I've read large chunks of Twisted's source but that one eluded me.

Comment: Is there a respectable way to find the port number? I know that the object returned by `listenTCP` has a private attribute `_realPortNumber`, but is there a way to get it without using that?

Comment: P.S. This is for a unit test for an HTTP client's GET method, and the idea is to find an unused port, publish a web server on it, and get that.

Comment: @PeterWestlake the easiest is to grab the returned object from listenTCP - https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.internet.interfaces.IListeningPort.html

Comment: Unit tests probably don't bind real HTTP ports.  Perhaps take a look at treq's RequestTraversalAgent.