# How to get the first available TCP port to listen to?

Tags: bash, networking, tcp, port

I want to attach my service to some TCP port, for testing purposes. Then, I will make calls to this port, make sure the service works, and shut it down. I need to find a way how to generate such a port number, since I can't use a fixed one - tests may run in parallel. Is it possible?

Comment: POSIX: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913501/how-to-let-kernel-choose-a-port-number-in-the-range-1024-5000-in-tcp-socket-pr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how I do it:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int main() {
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    socklen_t len = sizeof(addr);
    addr.sin_port = 0;
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock < 0) {
        perror("socket()");
        return -1;
    }
    if (bind(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, sizeof(addr)) != 0) {
        perror("bind()");
        return -1;
    }
    if (getsockname(sock, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, &len) != 0) {
        perror("getsockname()");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("%d\n", addr.sin_port);
    return 0;
}
```

Then, compile it and run:

```
cc -o reserve reserve.c && ./reserve
```

And it outputs the port number, available for binding.

I published a full version of the tool in Github: https://github.com/yegor256/random-tcp-port

Comment: Not initialising `struct sockaddr_in addr` to `0` might lead to undefeind behaviour, might crash the app.

Comment: Also one couldn`t rely on `AF_UNSPEC` being `#define`ed as `0`.

Comment: And you haven't said *why* this works. If indeed it does: I don't see how it can without initialising the socket address structure.

Comment: @alk you're right, I updated the answer with an explicit initialization of `addr.sin_port` to zero

Comment: You need to initialize more than `addr.sin_port`. You need to initalize `.sin_family` to `AF_INET` and `.sin_addr.s_addr` to `INADDR_ANY`.

Answer (score 2):

Just specify port zero when binding; then use `getsockname()` to find out what port was allocated, so you can tell your clients some other way what port you're listening at. Rarely useful.

Comment: IMO very useful for example during integration tests when you want to start a test server on whatever available port and then pass it to the corresponding test client. Also when you start a set of co-dependent child micro-services from a "parent" program.