# mktemp for TCP ports

Tags: linux, tcp

`mktemp` returns filename which is free (not associated to real file). So we can use that file.

How we can do the same with tcp ports?  Anybody knows `mkport` application?

( I need it from tests level. So I need just number. Then I will use it in two applications which will communicate on that tcp port. )

Comment: Are you asking how to obtain a free port for a server? Ordinarily you can just pass a `0` as the port number and the OS will pick one for you.

Comment: Thanks, I need just number. I've updated question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the first available TCP port to listen to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13308144/how-to-get-the-first-available-tcp-port-to-listen-to)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This python script might do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import socket

s = socket.socket()
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.listen(0)
print s.getsockname()[1]
```